# UL breaks html scroll inside dvs (when using display: box)

Tags: html, css

When i add a list (ul) to a div that uses display:box, then it breaks the scroll. It works fine with "p"-tags:

Working example (adjust browser window to see scroll): http://jsbin.com/ojeyuj

Non working example (ul-list): http://jsbin.com/ojeyuj/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inserted

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-box;
display: box;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-moz-box-orient: vertical;
-ms-box-orient: vertical;
box-orient: vertical;
```

at the top of the #box_inner2 css (before flex) and it worked for me. No clue why it doesn't work with both, but hopefully that solves your problem.

I never knew there was a display: box;, know a good place I can read up on them?

Comment: checking real quick it's the display: box part of code above that made it work for me.