# Positioning 4 divs

Tags: css, html

Okay so I've been trying to position these 4 divs for about 6 hours now. The routes box is suppose to take up whatever height is left between the navigation and info divs, wasn't quite sure how to say that. If someone could help me out or point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/41q3H.png

current code is at 98.214.131.200/new.php & 98.214.131.200/defualt.css

Comment: Please show the code that you have tried. Also it would be helpful if you created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that portrayed the problem.

Comment: show your code..........

Comment: @Kyomu... please try this as updated above. 98.214.131.200/new.php

Comment: That's the problem with DIVs that you can't say "height: auto;" and it expands automatically down to the next container. The easiest way to achieve this will be a Table solution. But I don't think you want to do this. Than another way will be with JavaScript to set the height of the div container.

Comment: @Kyomu There is a link to a drawing from paint already, I just couldn't post a picture since I only have 6rep. I have a feeling ShofunArts.de is right though.

Comment: @ShogunArts.de Couldn't [display:box](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10998702/1411473) be used for that effect? Not completely supported yet in all browsers, but an option. ([w3c draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/))

Comment: Never used display:box but maybe it can be achieved with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the `height:350px;` of class `.routes` it may help you.
 
**As Below:**

```
.routes {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0000FF;
    height: 350px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

**JSFIDDLE:**http://jsfiddle.net/beABW/

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
     <div style="background-Color:black;height:35px"></div>   
     <div style="width:30%;float:left;height:500px">
            <div style="height:50%;background-color:green;width:100%"></div>
            <div style="height:50%;background-color:blue;width:100%"></div>
     </div>
     <div  style="width:70%;float:right;height:500px;background-color:red"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works really well for 3 divs, but I also need a bar going across the top with a height of 35px

Comment: @TylerSiegrist : Add a div on top and give the height 35px.
am editing my code. Please check

Comment: I figured that out right after I posted that, the code is working. I don't want everything that currently is scaling to do so. The height of green&blue should fill the window but not overlap the black bar. Green & blue should also only have a width of 300px, then the red take whatever width & height is left. (see pic from original post)

Comment: @TylerSiegrist: the overlapping problem can be corrected by adding a margin-bottom:3px to the black div.
about the 300px and rest of the screen : You cannot mix both % and px together in width, for this particular problem, because % can vary from screen to screen. So You cannot get a cross browser solution. Either change that 300px to a certain % value and let the red div take rest(certain% value - 100).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="navigation"></div>

<div class="content">
   <div class="firstCol">
     <div class="routes"></div>
     <div class="info"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="secondCol">
     <div class="google_map"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

In your style.css

```
    .navigation{
       height:35px;
        width:100%;
    }

    .content{
        width:100%;
    }

    .firstCol{
       float:left;
       width:300px;
    height:auto;
    }

    .routes{
    width:300px
    height:auto;
    }


    .info{
    width:300px
    height:200px;
    }

    .secondCol{
       float:left;
       width:auto;
    height:auto;
    }

.google_map{
width:auto;
height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not know the height initially you will need to do this programmatically by getting the height of Google Map minus the height  of info and then setting routes to that height.   Example [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/set-height-of-a-div-equal-to-another-div).  Or you can use a table :-(

Comment: don't use a table ;p you'll make more problems than you'll solve

Comment: Not ideal, I agree but would work without javascript and not knowing the height.

Answer (score 0):

```
.class1
{
    float:left;
 }


#one
{
    height:35px;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid red;
    }

    #two
{
    height:200px;
    width:300px;
     border:1px solid red;
    }

#three {
    border: 1px solid Green;
    height: 403px;
}

    #four
{
    height:200px;
    width:300px;
     border:1px solid red;
    }

   #lftpanel {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}
 #rgtpanel {
    float: left;
    width: 808px;
}
```

---

```
<div id="mainDIv">
    <div id="one" class="class1">
    </div> 
    <div id="lftpanel">

        <div id="two" class="class1">
        </div>
    <div id="four" class="class1">
    </div> 
    </div> 
    <div id="rgtpanel">

    <div id="three" class="class1">
    </div> 
       </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited khurram's answer, the trick is, float everything and to take up whatever space is left use overflow:hidden (no float!)

Edit:
http://jsfiddle.net/hashie5/v4jFr/

Comment: This still doesn't make the routes & info box fill the height of the window

Answer (score 0):

Using [flex-boxes](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) may be what you are after. Flex-boxes can be used to stretch/grow a div to fill it's parent while taking into account other children of it's parent. I have an [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/48Nks/1/embedded/result/) of it doing what I believe your asking for.

Note: I'm not sure what browser versions this works in.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for a table solution (not very W3C but the solution will work in older browsers, too) :

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Header
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="300px">
            <table width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td width="100%">topleft</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="100%" height="200px">bottomleft</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td height="1000px">right</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I tried this before, but doesn't work:

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Header
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="300px">topleft</td>
        <td rowspan="2">right</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="300px" height="200px">bottomleft</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```